# Confused by Kullback-Leibler on conditional probability distributions

Tags: machine-learning, information-theory, bayesian, variational-analysis

I understand the Kullback-Leibler divergence well enough when it comes to a probability distribution over a single variable. However, I'm currently trying to teach myself variational methods and the use of the KL divergence in conditional probabilities is catching me out. [The source I'm working from is here](https://blog.evjang.com/2016/08/variational-bayes.html).

Specifically, the author represents the KL divergence as follows:

$$KL(Q_ϕ (Z|X)||P(Z|X)) = \sum_{z∈Z} q_ϕ (z|x) log\frac{q_ϕ (z|x)}{p(z|x)}$$

Where the confusion arises is on the summation across $Z$. Given that $z \in Z$ and $x \in X$, I would have expected (by analogy with conditional entropy) a double sum here of the form:

$$KL(Q_ϕ (Z|X)||P(Z|X)) = \sum_{z∈Z} \sum_{x∈X} q_ϕ (z|x) log\frac{q_ϕ (z|x)}{p(z|x)}$$

Otherwise, it seems to me that KL is only being calculated for one sample from $X$. Am I missing something basic here? And if my intuitions are off, any tips on getting them back on track would be useful––I'm teaching myself this stuff, so I don't have the benefit of formal instruction.

Comment: Would be useful to know a bit more about what's confusing you/not matching up with expectations. $KL(Q(Z|X) \| P(Z|X)$ is the KL-divergence between two conditional probability distributions, you are conditioning on $X$ & so you don't marginalise it out. You would equally write $KL(\tilde{Q} \| \tilde{P}) = \sum_z \tilde{q}(z) \log \frac{\tilde{q}(z)}{\tilde{p}(z)}$ where any mention of $x$ is thrown away until we actually need it again

Comment: Thanks for the input here. When you say "you are conditioning on X & so you don't marginalise it out"––that's where my confusion is. Let's say Z = {z<sub>1</sub>, z_2 , z_3} and X = {x_1 , x_2}. The conditional distributions Q(Z|X) and P(Z|X) must then––I think!––have as variables the set.

Comment: [Same comment as above, but with better formatting.] Thanks for the input here. When you say "you are conditioning on X & so you don't marginalise it out"––that's where my confusion is. Let's say $Z = {z_1, z_2 , z_3}$ and $X = {x_1 , x_2}$. The conditional distributions Q(Z|X) and P(Z|X) must then––I think!––have as variables the set Z x X. But when the KL doesn't sum across all the values of X, it seems to me that it's just conditioning on one value of X––say, $x_1$. Hence, it leaves out most of the distribution.

Comment: I think $X$ is a random variable, and $P(Z|X)$ is a posterior probability distribution.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

It depends on whether you are conditioning on a random variable or an event.

Given a random variable $x$,

$$
\operatorname{KL}[p(y \mid x) \,\|\, q(y \mid x)]
\doteq \iint p(\bar{x},\bar{y}) \ln\frac{p(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})}{q(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})} \mathrm{d}\bar{x} \mathrm{d}\bar{y}
\quad\text{or}\quad \sum_{\bar{x}}\sum_{\bar{y}} p(\bar{x},\bar{y}) \ln\frac{p(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})}{q(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})}.
$$

Given an event $\bar{x}$,

$$
\operatorname{KL}[p(y \mid \bar{x}) \,\|\, q(y \mid \bar{x})]
\doteq \int p(\bar{y}|\bar{x}) \ln\frac{p(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})}{q(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})} \mathrm{d}\bar{y}
\quad\text{or}\quad \sum_{\bar{y}} p(\bar{y}|\bar{x}) \ln\frac{p(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})}{q(\bar{y} \mid \bar{x})}.
$$

Note how conditioning on an event is equivalent to changing the probability distribution over its variable to a point mass. This is what turns the joint into a conditional above,

$$
p'(x,y) \doteq p(y|x)\delta_{\bar{x}}(x)=p(y|\bar{x}).
$$

To be more explicit, you can also choose instead of the KL conditioned on a random variable to use an expectation over event of the KL conditioned on those event,

$$
\operatorname{KL}[p(y \mid x) \,\|\, q(y \mid x)]
=\operatorname{E}_{\bar{x}\sim p(x)}\big[
  \operatorname{KL}[p(y \mid \bar{x}) \,\|\, q(y \mid \bar{x})]
\big].
$$

Mixing up random variables and event is quite common but it's often easy to know from the context which is meant.

Comment: Thanks, this is a source of some really good intuition, especially the way you pinpoint the error as a confusion of a variable and an outcome.

Comment: @Lodore66 Glad it's helpful. Feel free to accept the answer so that it shows up on top for other visitors.

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite see what confuses you. Think about how we compute, for example, a conditional expectation: $E(Z \mid X)=\sum_Z P(Z \mid X) $ : that is, we sum only over $Z$, and the result is a function of the conditioning variable $X$. (Put in other way, your each value of $X$ we have that $P(Z \mid X=x)$ is a different probability distribution - and hence for each value of $X$ we have different values of the (conditioned to $X=x$) expectation, variance, etc). The same happens here. And the conditioned KL divergence is not a number, but a function of $X$.

Comment: This is exactly what i wasn't getting: 

"each value of X we have that P(Z∣X=x) is a different probability distribution - and hence for each value of X we have different values of the (conditioned to X=x) expectation, variance, etc)."

I thought the KL outputted a value for each P(Z∣X=x) , not a distribution, and that was why I kept thinking that the divergence calculated a unique value for P(Z|X), not a range of values for each x ∈ X. Thanks so much!

Comment: I think that's reasonably confusing, given how $H(Y|X)$ in information theory is usually taken to be a value and not a random variable. It makes a lot of sense though, but the right hand side of the definition should really use capital $X$ rather than $x$.

Comment: $P(Z|X)$ is a posterior distribution right. I think the op was confused by the expectation of posterior distribution.

Comment: This answer is not quite correct. You can condition a KL divergence either on an outcome or on a random variable, both are fine. The example of an expectation also confuses random variables and outcomes and missing a variable. It should probably be $E[Z|X]$ = sum_z P(Z=z | X) * z.